# Androids 8,9, 12 format SD card to "read only" - only for non-android devices

Tags: sd-card, 9.0-pie, 8.0-oreo, android-12, formatting

I formatted two different SD cards with Android 8, 9 and 12. In all cases, the SD cards are write protected for my laptop (SD card reader) - but not for the Phones, or when connecting phone via USB. In those cases I maintain write access.

Any pointers on how to undo that?

Comment: Do you use an SD card adapter from microSD to regular SD card? If yes the adapter may the problem. A simple problem would be if the write protect selector of the adapter would be in the wrong position. Also possible is that the adapter was produced "too cheap" and now doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Nevermind.... it's my arch and manjaro laptops that mess up. On GF's linux mint, all is fine :-S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn's out, it's not Android but Arch Linux based systems (Arch and Manjaro).
On Linux Mint, all is well...

Marking this as answer, will look for solution elsewhere.

**EDIT** If sbdy stumbles accross this: the actual solution was to ... reboot after Linux Kernel updates. So much time wasted -_-" ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/5hrdvn/my_arch_doesnt_recognize_usb_sticks_anymore_how/))